# List of standard modules and packages in any python release

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have to release a Python application which works pretty well on python 2.7.3 (becuase it was developed on this version). **It is one of the requirement that it should work with the standard python modules/packages** which are available out of box after Python installation.

How would I know **which is the least python version** on which this application is supported. I need to mention this information in the release notes and it's not practical for me to install all the python releases and test the application.

Just for information, it uses following modules and packages which are standard in python 2.7.3

```
urllib2
cookielib
urllib
ast
sys
sqlite3
os
argparse
logging
re
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick would be to 1st check the documents for each of the imports:

- urllib2 - *Beginning in Python 2.3..*
- cookielib - *New in version 2.4.*
- urllib - *Changed in version 2.3: Added the proxies support. Changed in version 2.6: Added getcode() to returned object and support for the no_proxy environment variable.*
- ast - *New in version 2.6: The high-level ast module containing all helpers.*
- sys - *Been there from about 1.0*
- sqlite3 - *New in version 2.5.*
- os - *Been there from about 1.0*
- argparse - ***New in version 2.7***
- logging - *New in version 2.3.*
- re - *Present for some time*

Comment: No problem @VivekJha - just a matter of looking in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**Knowing which modules your program uses is not enough** to ensure compatibility with any given version, since the modules themselves may change between versions. For example, [`os.resuid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.setresuid) is only available since python 2.7

If you're absolutely not able to test the different versions (which would be very recommended), you'll need to **check the documentation for every function of every module that you use**. Note that there may be changes that are not mentioned there.

Comment: Is there any system/application/cloud based tool which helps to test a pyhon application for different versions of python. We have similar clould based tools for testing compatibility with different browsers, something on the same lines

Comment: @VivekJha Not that I know of, but you may want to ask that as a new question